# ListTile at the bottom of the screen

Tags: flutter, dart

I want a List Tile from my Menu at the bottom of the screen. I done it with a Sized box, it worked for my Nokia 7.1, but when I debug with another phone with a another resulution the solution doesn´t work, because I customized the box for the Nokia and not for another phones. Now I don´t konw how I can do it. I tried by using an Container istead of a Drawer, but it doesn´t slove the problem. Here is my Code:

```
   return Drawer(
      child: ListView(
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        children: <Widget>[
          DrawerHeader(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.green,
            ),
            child: Text(
              'Menü',
              style: GoogleFonts.oswald(
                textStyle: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontSize: 45,
                )
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

[ListTiles]
This is the List Tile I want at the bottom:

```
          // this is my first attempt:
          /*SizedBox(
            height: 410,
          ),*/

          ListTile(
          leading: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_outlined,
            color: Colors.black,
            size: 30,
          ),
          title: Text('Back',
            style: GoogleFonts.raleway(
              textStyle: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
                fontSize: 30,
              )
            )
          ),
          onTap: () => Navigator.pop(context),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Try my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68707124/13997210) hope its helpful to you.

Comment: Your Solution from the question there doesn´t work for me

Comment: It creates a complete white screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by the `ListView` combined with `physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()`, I think a refactor to the following solution might also work for you (condensed for brevity):

```
Drawer(child:
  CustomScrollView(
    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
    slivers: <Widget>[
      SliverToBoxAdapter(child:
        Column(children: [
          DrawerHeader(decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.green), child: Text('Menü')),
            // all of your list tiles
          ],
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        ),
      ),
      SliverFillRemaining(child:
        Align(child:
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_outlined, color: Colors.black, size: 30),
            title: Text('Back'),
            onTap: () => Navigator.pop(context),
          ),
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        ),
        hasScrollBody: false,
      )
    ],
  )
)
```

Comment: That workes, but now is the green box not as wide as the menu.

Comment: whoops, missed that. I added a `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,` to the `Column`, in the code example. Does that fix it?