# Set Drawer Header at the top

Tags: flutter, dart

my Drawer Header title is not there where I want it. I tried to positionig it further up, but I failed. Here is a picture of the top from the drawer:

[image]

The "Menü" is the text I want to positionig further up.

Here is the part of my Code:

```
          Column(children: [
              DrawerHeader(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.green,
                ),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text('Menü',
                      style: GoogleFonts.oswald(
                        textStyle: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontSize: 45,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope its helpful to you.

Refer Drawer [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/design/drawer)

```
 Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(title: Text(title)),
  body: const Center(
    child: Text('My Page!'),
  ),
  drawer: Drawer(
    child: ListView(
      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
      children: [
        const DrawerHeader(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.blue,
          ),
          child: Text('Drawer Header'),
        ),
        ListTile(
          title: const Text('Item 1'),
        ),
        ListTile(
          title: const Text('Item 2'),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
)
```

Your result screen-> [image]

Comment: I think I can´t use this, because I use a Column for a back ListTile at the end of the Drawer look here: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70613915/listtile-at-the-bottom-of-the-screen). Another thing I think the problem here is that I use a big font size.

Comment: See the comment of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70613915/listtile-at-the-bottom-of-the-screen) question this is my comment  and refer this answer